# LinQ To SQL with UPDLOCK

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to use UPDLOCK with LinQ To SQL? I have a scenario that needs it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq2SQL currently doesn't support issuing an UPDLOCK

More info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/24890e00-f224-4f6a-a596-f9b2f524aa39) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190666/linq-to-sql-and-concurrency-issues)

if you need to do this, you can wrap your own SQL in a SPROC and have L2S execute the SPROC instead

Comment: Thanks Eoin!! I already have a PROC to do this, but I was trying to do that in my Application. It's a shame L2S doesn't support that.